# Tensorflow-GPU: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cudnn

I am facing the error below despite I have installed `CUDA`, `cuDNN`, and `tensorflow-gpu` package alongside adding them to the `PATH` when I try to run a simple `CNN` network. The detail of my software stack is added below:

```
TensorFlow: 1.14.0
Keras: 2.3.0
TensorFlow-GPU: 1.14.0
CUDA: 10.1
cuDNN: 7
```

**Full error stacktrace:**

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2066, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2060, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1411, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1418, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/PyCharmProjects/keras-fer/fer_ck_1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-PqSTp19f\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, Cuda version 10.1 which is not supported by TF-GPU yet. Please first completely remove Cuda 10.1 version and then install Cuda 10. Although, I am not sure if this will resolve your issue but at least it will not make you fall into Cuda 10.1 version usage issues. You can read the requirements [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements).
Let us know if you are still facing the issue after installing Cuda 10.